# Postgres json alias

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I write SQL-query in PostgreSQL. I have now:

```
SELECT T.order,
 (SELECT row_to_json(item) FROM (
    SELECT T.title, T.subtitle, T.text
     FROM table T
     WHERE T.id = 1
) AS item)
FROM table T
WHERE T.id = 1;
```

The result is:

```
order |               row_to_json                                                         

---------------+------------------------------------------------------
    2 | {"title":"AAA","subtitle":"aaaa","text":"aaaa"}
```

But I need result:

```
order |               row_to_json                                                         

---------------+------------------------------------------------------
    2 | {"item":{"title":"AAA","subtitle":"aaaa","text":"aaaa"}}
```

Could you tell me how I can get it?

Comment: here `item` is just a subquery alias - are you sure you want alias in json?..

Comment: It's a subquery. I need to get the same result from few tables and then sort it by order. And if I want to know which result from which table I need to have alias for every result.
Item is just alias.

Comment: If `id` is the primary key of that table, then why use a subquery at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't need subquery for such result and using [Postgres jsonb function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) `jsonb_build_object` you can achieve your goal like that:

```
-- Test data:
WITH    "table"( id, "order", title, subtitle, "text" ) AS (
            VALUES  (   1::int, 2::int, 'AAA'::text, 'aaaa'::text, 'aaaa'::text),
                    (   2::int, 3::int, 'BBB'::text, 'bbbb'::text, 'bbbb'::text)
        )
-- The query:
SELECT  "order",
        jsonb_build_object(
            'items',
            jsonb_build_object(
                'title', title,
                'subtitle', subtitle,
                'text', "text"
            )
        ) AS myjson
FROM    "table"
WHERE   id = 1;

-- Result:
 order |                             myjson
-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
     2 | {"items": {"text": "aaaa", "title": "AAA", "subtitle": "aaaa"}}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you! It's what I need.